# Botão para adicionar valor numérico, gravar no banco PostgreSQL e mostrar na tela com PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Seguinte, estou trabalhando em um projeto de um sistema que tem como um dos parâmetros "série".. Eu preciso que a partir do botão "Salvar" ele pegue o valor da série, salve ele no postgresql e mostre o número seguinte na tela..

Exemplo: Série:'0002', clica no botão 'Salvar', adiciona no banco, mostra na tela o número seguinte:'0003' para que se possa fazer um novo cadastro..

Eu sei que é simples, mas nunca trabalhei com php e estou fazendo na raça rs

Agradeço a ajuda!

parte da série:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
 <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Série</label>
 <input name="serie" id="idserie" class="form-control" type="text" 
 value="00001" disabled>
</div>
```

parte do salvar:

```
</div>
 <button id="btnslv" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" 
 name="button">SALVAR</button>
</div>
```

parte em php:

```
<?php
 //inicia uma conexão com o banco de dados orcamentos.
 require "orcamento.php";
 require "conexao.php";

if ($conn) {
 function slvserie (){
 $sre_id = $_GET['serie'];
 $SQL = "INSERT INTO dds_cli(sre_id) VALUES ({$sre_id})";
 pg_query($conn, $sql);
 echo "++Registro inserido com sucesso!!";
 pg_close($conn);
}
}
else
{
echo "++ Falha na conexão com o PostgreSQL!!";
}
?>
```

Não estou usando nenhum framework.

Comment: Recomendo editar e colocar o código que tem em php e o HTML (basicamente a parte do form), está usando algum framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então se percebi o teu problema tu queres indicar uma incrementação para isso podes simplesmente criar outra tabela na tua BD, sendo o valor indicado nesta nova tabela simplesmente criado e inserido nesta ao carregar esta pagina se o botão que tu desejas seja primida pode fazer isso com a função `isset()` em `php`

```
if (isset($_POST['valordoteubotao')
{
    o teu codigo ;
}
```

Podes então recuperar o valor do numero de serie desta tabela e modificar-lo por incrementação se alguma condição for respeitada.
para manter uma ordem na incrementação uma forma e de verificar sempre o valor anterior e declarar a próxima entrada como sendo o valor "anterior++";

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria o seguinte.

Primeiro, gravaria uma sessão no php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['serie'] = 1;
```

Na tela do formulário, vc pode imprimir a session usando sprintf, assim mantém o formato desejado ([documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php)):

```
echo sprintf('%04s', $_SESSION['serie']);
```

Depois de salvar os dados no banco, basta incrementar a Session:

```
$_SESSION['serie']++;
```

Outra alternativa seria pegar o total de registros da tabela usando "SELECT COUNT(sre_id) total FROM dds_cli" e incrementar esse valor em uma variável.

Espero que ajude.